# Get Signatures from Outlook and Detecting Body format

Tags: c#, outlook

I am using COM API to compose an e-mail.

```
 objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
 mic = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
 mic.To = ccase.Email;
 mic.CC = ccase.CC;
 mic.Subject = ccase.Subject;
 mic.Body = bodyBuffer.ToString();
// below line throws exception ?? Shouldn't it just use what is defined in outlook.
mic.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatUnspecified;
```

Question:

1. I want to define body to be plain Text, HTML, or Rich Text based upon what is defined in Outlook by the customer.
2. How can I retrieve the e-mail signature from Outlook and add it to the end of body ?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Karephul

Comment: Did you find a way to get those signatures?

Answer (score 2):

We decided not to do this as users might have configured multiple signatures. So, let users add signature in the end.